# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/var/www/app/>

Tags: .net, linux, nginx, devops

I am running dotnet core 1.9 console project. Ran into the following error when trying to run it from Debian11.

steps to build and deploy to nginx service:
dotnet clean
dotnet restore -r debian-x64
dotnet build -r debian-x64
dotnet publish . -c Release -r debian-x64 -o /var/www/app

logs of the nginx service:
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
The application was run as a self-contained app because '/var/www/app/ApiServices.runtimeconfig.json'
If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the '/var/www/app/ApiServices.runtimeconfig.json'
api.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=131/n/a
api.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this version of dotnet is not supported.

The solution is to upgrade to new version of dotnet core.